# JS- How to convert an array with key and value pairs to an object?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

```
var arr = [];
arr['k1'] = 100;
console.log(arr); //o/p - [k1: 100]
arr.length;       //o/p - 0
window.copy(arr);   //copies: []
```

I want to convert this array-like object to a proper obj i.e,

`arr = { k1: 100}`

So doing **window.copy(arr)** should copy **{k1:100}**

NOTE- I need to do this as Node.js express server returns empty arrays in response for such cases.

Comment: Why not use an object to begin with? That's not what an array should be used for

Comment: `arr['k1'] = 100` doesn't do what you think it does. It doesn't create an ***index*** called `k1` with a value of `100`. It creates an entirely new property on this instance of an Array called `k1` and sets the value to `100`.  If you were to loop over the array indexes, you'd never see `k1` show up and it is why the `.length` is `0`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use object spread syntax to copy all own enumerable properties from the original object to a new object:

```js
const arr = [];
arr['k1'] = 100;
const obj = { ...arr };

console.log(obj);
```

This works even if `arr` is originally an array, rather than a plain object, because the `k1` property exists directly on the array.

(But ideally, one should never have code that assigns to arbitrary properties of an array - better to refactor it to use an object in such a situation to begin with)

Answer (score 1):

```js
var array = []
array["k1"] = 100;
var newObject = Object.assign({},array);
console.log(newObject);
```